# Send/receive data through socket using python and ctype Structure

Tags: python, structure, ctypes

I am trying to send and receive C structure data from a python client to server and vice-versa. Both clients and server work smoothly in connecting and exchanging data. Client sends a ctype structure to server and server sends it back again. The problem is that I don't know how to interpret the message received in the client and extract the data as it is in the structure format. My final Idea is to have a python server and C-client talking to each other and exchanging data in a predefined structure.

Here are the codes I have for client and server in Python:

**Client Code**

```
import socket
import sys
import time

from ctypes import *

class payload_t(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("ms", c_ulong),
                ("counter", c_ulong),
                ("DHT_temperature", c_float),
                ("DHT_humidity", c_float),
                ("DS_temperature", c_float),
                ("temperature_setpoint", c_float),
                ("time_setpoint", c_float)]

# Create a TCP/IP socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

# Connect the socket to the port where the server is listening
server_address = ('localhost', 10000)
print >>sys.stderr, 'connecting to %s port %s' % server_address
sock.connect(server_address)

try:
    for i in range(0,10):
        # Send data
        payload=payload_t(i*1000,i+1,25.2,45.7,25.8,33.22,3600.0)
        message = payload
        # 'This is the message.  It will be repeated.'
        print 'length of message %d' % sizeof(message)
        print 'sending "', message.ms, message.counter, message.DHT_temperature, message.DHT_humidity, message.DS_temperature, message.temperature_setpoint, message.time_setpoint, '"'
        sock.sendall(message)
        # time.sleep(0.1)
        # Look for the response
        amount_received = 0
        amount_expected = sizeof(message)

        while amount_received < amount_expected:
            datap = sock.recv(sizeof(message))
            amount_received += len(datap)
        print >>sys.stderr, 'received "%s"' % datap
        print type(datap)
        payload=payload_t()
        datap.readinto(payload)
        data=datap.readinto(payload_t)
        data=struct.unpack(payload_t,datap)
            print 'Received "', data.ms, data.counter, data.DHT_temperature, data.DHT_humidity, data.DS_temperature, data.temperature_setpoint, data.time_setpoint, '"'

finally:
    print >>sys.stderr, 'closing socket'
    sock.close()
```

**Server Code**

```
import socket
import sys
from ctypes import *

class payload_t(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("ms", c_ulong),
                ("counter", c_ulong),
                ("DHT_temperature", c_float),
                ("DHT_humidity", c_float),
                ("DS_temperature", c_float),
                ("temperature_setpoint", c_float),
                ("time_setpoint", c_float)]

# Create a TCP/IP socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

# Bind the socket to the port
server_address = ('localhost', 10000)
print >>sys.stderr, 'starting up on %s port %s' % server_address
sock.bind(server_address)

# Listen for incoming connections
sock.listen(1)
payload=payload_t(0,0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0)
while True:
    # Wait for a connection
    print >>sys.stderr, 'waiting for a connection'
    connection, client_address = sock.accept()

    try:
        print >>sys.stderr, 'connection from', client_address

        # Receive the data in small chunks and retransmit it
        while True:
            data = connection.recv(sizeof(payload))
            print >>sys.stderr, 'received "%s"' % data
            if data:
                print >>sys.stderr, 'sending data back to the client'
                connection.sendall(data)
            else:
                print >>sys.stderr, 'no more data from', client_address
                break

    finally:
        # Clean up the connection
        connection.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are currently dumping the received data. You are reassigning the variable 'datap' in every loop iteration.

Do something like that instead:

```
datap += sock.recv(sizeof(message) - amount_received)
```

(Of course it's not the most efficient code, but you get the idea.)

When you have your structure assembled in the 'datap' var, you load it into your ctype class using 'from_buffer' or 'from_buffer_copy' method.

```
payload = payload_t.from_buffer_copy(datap)
```

The latter is better in your case, since your buffer may go away when you rebind the 'datap' var.

Comment: Thanks! It did work perfectly. Moreover, obviously, I just have to initialize the payload every step.

Answer (score -1):

What about providing an instance of ctypes.Structure directly with the call recv_into?

Here is a modified version of your Server code, hoping I did not remove a functionality you wanted to keep

```
import socket
import sys
from ctypes import *

class payload_t(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("ms", c_ulong),
                ("counter", c_ulong),
                ("DHT_temperature", c_float),
                ("DHT_humidity", c_float),
                ("DS_temperature", c_float),
                ("temperature_setpoint", c_float),
                ("time_setpoint", c_float)]

# Create a TCP/IP socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

# Bind the socket to the port
server_address = ('localhost', 10000)
print >>sys.stderr, 'starting up on %s port %s' % server_address
sock.bind(server_address)

# Listen for incoming connections
sock.listen(1)
payload=payload_t()
while True:
    # Wait for a connection
    print >>sys.stderr, 'waiting for a connection'
    connection, client_address = sock.accept()

    try:
        print >>sys.stderr, 'connection from', client_address

        # Receive the data in small chunks and retransmit it
        while True:
            data = connection.recv_into(payload)
            print >>sys.stderr, 'received "%s"' % data
            if data:
                print >>sys.stderr, 'sending data back to the client'
                print >>sys.stderr, 'time_setpoint "%f"' % payload.time_setpoint
                connection.sendall(payload)
            else:
                print >>sys.stderr, 'no more data from', client_address
                break

    finally:
        # Clean up the connection
        connection.close()
```

So, basically, the only thing I did was using a socket.recv_into call directly into an instance of your structure:
**https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.recv_into**

That gives me direct access to the structure attributes afterward.

I guess the structure is small enough (28 octets) so that data fits in a single recv_into call. If you need multiple calls to recv_into to get your full structure built up, then...

If you have python 3.7, you could make multiple calls to your structure with slicing memoryviews:

```
mv = memoryview(payload).cast('B')
size = sizeof(payload)
while size > 0:
    data = connection.recv_into(mv) 
    mv = mv[data:] 
    size -= data
```

Nothing guaranteed to be honest. With earlier versions of Python, you could have an exception when trying to cast 'B' on your memoryview. Recall that memoryview on a ctypes.Structure is 0-dim, and then it is almost impossible slicing it without the cast...

Comment: Yeah, what about that? Can you explain further how this could solve the problem?